# Android schedule a SyncAdapter sync in 10s when I received GCM?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, android-wake-lock

<s>I have my BAAS set to sending a GCM push every time data changes on server. Sometimes the user can modify a bunch of items at once which will each count as one update to my database and trigger a bunch of GCM pushes. Unfortunately, adding a cooldown period server side to limit the amount of actual gcm messages is a little more complicated than expected. So instead, I am receiving all those gcm messages and then I decide depending on how long ago the last sync was, whether or not to sync again.</s>

EDIT: I have figured out how to implement a cooldown period on my GCM pushes, however, I actually still need to know how to schedule a SyncAdapter sync in X seconds.

When my WakefulBroadcastReceiver receives a GCM message, I have some logic that decides whether or not to initiate a sync. If I consume a GCM message and decide for whatever reason not sync instantly (eg synced VERY recently), then I have to schedule a sync in the very near future eg 10s. Otherwise, I have to wait till the next GCM message until my logic decides whether or not to sync and there is no telling when the next GCM message will be.

So how do I do that? My WakefulBroadcastReceiver starts an IntentService. I tried something like this in the IntentService:

```
onHandleIntent(Intent intent){

    if I sync, then completeWakefulIntent

    else if I dont sync, postDelayed(sync, and then completeWakefulIntent)
}
```

But it didn't seem to work.

What about if when I consume a gcm and dont sync, I add a periodic sync of 10s to my SyncAdapter and then remove the periodic sync back when onPerformSync() runs? That seems kind of hacky.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Any errors thrown by your `onHandleIntent`?

One option I think would work is if you specify the delay while inside the activity that would be performing the sync.

Simply pass in an extra into the bundle sent to `GcmIntentService` specifying that you need a delay to be done.

Hope this works out for you.